# How do I convert hh:mm:ss.000 to milliseconds in Excel?

Tags: excel, time

I have a device which outputs the time in the format `hh:mm:ss.000`, e.g., 00:04:58.727 and I need to convert these to milliseconds.

I can't change the way the device outputs the times so I have to do it in Excel, but I don't know VB so am looking for a cell-by-cell solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using some text manipulation we can separate each unit of time and then sum them together with their millisecond coefficients.

To show the formulas in the cells use CTRL + `

---

[image: Raw data view]

---

[image: Formula view]

Comment: This is a very cumbersome solution. See Jon49's below for a much easier one.

Answer (score 53):

Let's say that your time value is in cell `A1` then in `A2` you can put:

```
=A1*1000*60*60*24
```

or simply:

```
=A1*86400000
```

What I am doing is taking the decimal value of the time and multiply it by 1000 (milliseconds) and 60 (seconds) and 60 (minutes) and 24 (hours).

You will then need to format cell `A2` as General for it to be in milliseconds format.

If your time is a text value then use:

```
=TIMEVALUE(A1)*86400000
```

**UPDATE**

Per @dandfra's comment this solution may not work in the Italian version of Excel.

Comment: Agreed. This is a much better solution. Just to clarify, this method works because Excel stores time values as a decimal fraction of a single day (24 hour period). So midnight is 0.0000, noon is 0.5000, 9pm is 0.875000.

Comment: Didn't work for me (#VALUE!), maybe due to regional settings different than US

Comment: @AFract, Regional differences shouldn't make a difference. Time is the same everywhere (I don't know of any place that doesn't have 60 seconds in a minute, etc). Is your time a string? Did you try `TIMEVALUE` first, if you have a string instead of a timevalue?

Comment: @Jon49 > of course time is the same everywhere, but I thought it may be a kind of separator issue or something like  that. Maybe I had an hidden character in my string or sth. I'll do a new try if I still need it. Thanks

Comment: For those with trouble because of regional settings different than US (english), for example my german version of TIMEVALUE is ZEITWERT. excel thinks it's good to localize function names.

Comment: This does not work in the italian version of excel (and the problem is not the name of the function, TIMEVALUE corresponds to ORARIO.VALORE and it returns #VALORE!)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
=LEFT(B2, 2)*3600000 + MID(B2,4,2) * 60000 + MID(B2,7,2)*1000 + RIGHT(B2,3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

cell[B1]: 0:04:58.727

cell[B2]: =FIND(".";B1)

cell[B3]: =LEFT(B1;B2-7)

cell[B4]: =MID(B1;11-8;2)

cell[B5]: =RIGHT(B1;6)

cell[B6]: =B3*3600000+B4*60000+B5

maybe you have to multiply B5 also with 1000.

=FIND(".";B1) is only necessary because you might have inputs like '0:04:58.727' or '10:04:58.727' with different length.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing string manipulation, you can use the HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND functions to break apart the time.  You can then multiply by 60*60*1000, 60*1000, and 1000 respectively to get milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a single formula:

```
=(RIGHT(D2,3))+(MID(D2,7,2)*1000)+(MID(D2,4,2)*60000)+(LEFT(D2,2)*3600000)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
=(RIGHT(E9;3))+(MID(E9;7;2)*1000)+(MID(E9;5;2)*3600000)+(LEFT(E9;2)*216000000)
```

Maybe you need to change semi-colon by coma...

Comment: and it has semicolons

Comment: @Sogger Semi colons are linked to the culture where it has been written, works fine on my computer by example.

Comment: Good to know, didn't think of that!