# Average time in milliseconds

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I cannot get the average of times in milliseconds, using the average function returns `#DIV/0!`

And why excel detect that i'm dividing by zero? 
what function can i use to return the average of the following:

```
00:00:00.2154647
00:00:00.2452687
00:00:00.2631118
00:00:00.2634366
00:00:00.0500521
00:00:00.0468655
00:00:00.0034620
00:00:00.0052060
00:00:00.0040070
00:00:00.0037784
00:00:00.0042271
00:00:00.0037236
00:00:00.0032318
00:00:00.0047810
```

the cell formatted to Time.

Comment: using AVERAGE() works fine here   = 00:00:00.080

Comment: Do you need to keep all the decimals, milliseconds only gives you 3 decimals after the seconds

Comment: No i don't need to keep all decimal, the result is copied from another application, i don't mind keeping only 3 digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this answer to convert time to milliseconds

[convert to milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183698/how-do-i-convert-hhmmss-000-to-milliseconds-in-excel)

you use 7 digits for milliseconds so you for the milliseconds

```
=RIGHT(A1;7) / 100000
```

then Average the Results

```
=AVERAGE(B1:B??)
```

Comment: +1 - this is the only way, I think, if all 7 decimals are to be retained....although the method will need to be adjusted to do that

Answer (score 0):

Excel only recognises milliseconds, i.e. 3 decimal places after the seconds, as you have more decimals you must have text values, which is why you get #DIV/0! error, that's the standard result when there are no numbers in the range.

You can still average those values unchanged, though, with an array formula, e.g. with data in `A2:A15` use this formula

`=AVERAGE(A2:A15+0)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

format result cell as `hh:mm:ss.000` and you should get `00:00:00.080` as K_B says

There can't be any real text values in the range otherwise you get an error

using the +0 converts text values to times, although you'll lose the "precision" of the extra decimals

.....or you can convert your data to real times like this

Select column of data then use Data > Text to columns > Finish > format range as `hh:mm:ss.000`

That should convert to real time values and you can use a regular AVERAGE function to average those