# AFRACT`s Error Message (#VALUE!) to JON49`s to How do I convert hh:mm:ss.000 to milliseconds in Excel?

Tags: excel

Apologies for opening a thread instead of posting comment on the Return-of-the-Archons Thread but i am not allowed to post anything since i do not have 50 reputation. I have the very same problem as AFRACT in [How do I convert hh:mm:ss.000 to milliseconds in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183698/how-do-i-convert-hhmmss-000-to-milliseconds-in-excel/8184382#8184382?newreg=de03322a9ed44d58a51075a0bd979b1a)

Like probably AFRACT my data is in timestamp: 00:00:00.000 and is generated by a device to measure physiological data (heartrate, EDA, Skin Temp) and i want it to change to total seconds.miliseconds. I tried what JON49 proposed but got the (#VALUE!) Error, and then with timevalue, i got the (NAME!) Error. I have Excel 2016 and I am in Middle Europe (Germany)

Comment: Multiply by `A1*60*60*24` and format as `0.000`.

Answer (score 0):

A date is simply 1 for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Time is a decimal portion of a day; e.g. today is 42,800 and today at noon is 42,800.5. A true second is `0.0000115740740740741`

If you want the seconds as integers with the milliseconds as decimal portion of 1 then multiply your true time value by 86,400 (i.e. 60*60*24) and format the cell as a number with three decimal places; e.g. `0.000`.

[image]

If you want the time as a true time value then simply use a custom number format of `[s].000`. In the above image, C1 holds `=A1` and is formatted as `[s].000`.