# Java Duration giving different result to Excel

Tags: java, excel, duration, localdate

have a method that calculates the difference between 2 LocalDateTimes. I have worked out some test data in Excel, but the Java method isn't tallying up with my Excel formula. I'm guessing ym Excel formula is wrong but can anyone tell me why?

```
    private Duration difference(LocalDateTime request, LocalDateTime response) {
    Duration duration = Duration.between(request, response);
    System.out.println("difference: " + duration.toMillis());
    return duration;
}
```

My input data:
Request: 2018-02-12T13:43:46.456    Response: 2018-02-12T14:43:54.123

Excel formula result: 3608333 millis
Java method: 3607667 millis

My excel formula is the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183698/how-do-i-convert-hhmmss-000-to-milliseconds-in-excel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Looking at the last three digits, it looks like the excel formula confuses request and response. xxx123 -xxx456 should be xxx667, not xxx333.

Comment: In the linked answer I read your first formula as `=LEFT(A2,2)`, but my Excel will not accept that as a formula. It says “There's a problem with this formula.” No further explanation. :-(

Comment: Thanks, @pnuts, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator (OP) is 'confused', Excel is not. Taking the same approach as the Accepted answer referred to:

[image: Millisecond diffeence]

The formulae displayed in Row1 and Row6 are as used for Rows3,4,5, and 7 after copying down.

Less cumbersome (but the same result of `3607667`) from the time element of the examples:

```
=(TIMEVALUE(A5)-TIMEVALUE(A4))*86400000
```

or if to be applied to the entire DateTTime strings in the same cells as above:

```
=(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A5,12))-TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A4,12)))*86400000
```

The *Excel* result in all these cases:

### 3607667

Comment: Normally we shouldn’t post “cannot reproduce” or “your code is working for me” as an answer, but with this level of explanation and bonus info I find it warranted. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Malte Hartwig was right.

"Looking at the last three digits, it looks like the excel formula confuses request and response. xxx123 -xxx456 should be xxx667, not xxx333"